# sublabel parenthesis changed to mathmode using subfig.sty

Tags: parentheses, subfig

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}%
\captionsetup[subfloat]{%
font=normalsize,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\label{fig:eBoxEndowment}]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{10821_001_fig_001a.pdf}}\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:eBoxPrices}]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{10821_001_fig_001b.pdf}}
\caption{The Edgeworth box. The axes along which the endowment and
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I got the output as:

[image]

How can I change the `sublabel` parenthesis into `mathmode`, i.e., `(a)` should come as `$($a$)$`,... Please suggest

Comment: Do you see a difference between `(a)` and `$($a$)$`?

Comment: @samcarter I need those parenthesis should be in math font, currently it came in text font...

Comment: Can you come up with an example where one can see a difference between parenthesis in math and text font?

Comment: @samcarter if you have the font "Melior" family, then check the parenthesis style, it looks like square bracket, I am using MtPro2 family for math, so only I want to change the parenthesis to set in Mathfont in all places...

Comment: Should the parenthesis be replaced only for the subfigure labels or in all the text?

Comment: @samcarter Yes, need to fix the parenthesis to be set in Math font everywhere...

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48854/36296 could help

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, that answer is useful for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but I'm using LaTeX and PDFLaTeX to generate the output...

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the subcaption package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font+=normalsize,labelformat=simple,labelsep=space]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{$($\alph{subfigure}$)$}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:eBoxEndowment}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:eBoxPrices}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{The Edgeworth box. The axes along which the endowment and}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this what already I did temporally, if we using this, cross references (\label and \ref) also got affected...

Comment: @MadyYuvi you can set the format of `\ref` separately if it should look differently -- see the `subcaption` documentation for an example.