# Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textlangle not provided by [\textlangle]

Tags: errors, textcomp

In my thesis, I cite many orthographic forms in angular brackets. Until now, I had just been typing angular brackets and an explicit whitespace after (<word>), but I would like to switch to some nicer looking angular brackets I could put via a command which automatically includes the whitespace and would allow me to change the typesetting for all forms simultaneously (something like `\Angular{word}`).

From this post: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48448/angle-brackets-in-non-math-mode-text] I got the idea of using the `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` command from the textcomp package and define a new command like this:

```
\usepackage{textcomp,xspace}
\newcommand{\Ang}[1]{\textlangle\xspace{#1}\textrangle\xspace}
```

In an article-class document where I did the test, it worked just fine, but in the larger report-class document of my thesis I get the error: "

```
Problem with textcomp package - Symbol \textlangle not provided by
[\Angular{word}]
```

I also tried directly typing `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` into my document, but receive the error:

```
Symbol \textlangle not provided by
[\textlangle]
```

Is there maybe something in my preamble which works against the textcomp package and the new command, or what could be the problem?

My preamble looks like this (I am sorry if it looks messy, I add new packages and commands every time I stumble upon a new problem to solve while thesis writing but don't know if there is a way to have a more "organized" preamble?):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %Schriftgröße 12 pt; hidelinks in die [] einfügen wenn Links versteckt sein sollen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=40mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry} % innerer Seitenrand 3 cm, äußerer 4 cm, oben u. unten je 3
%\usepackage{a4wide} % fuer schmalere Seitenraender

\usepackage{setspace} % für ZeilenabstandLa entrada \enquote{Sillero}, escrita 
\spacing{1.45} % entspricht in etwa Zeilenabstand 1.5 in word
%\doublespacing

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %,ngerman,spanish, english %\foreignlanguage{spanish}{text}

\usepackage{fontspec-xetex}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{% my custom formatting for expex glosses
    belowglpreambleskip=-0.1ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the preamble and the top gloss line
    %everygla=\footnotesize,% removes the default italic formatting of the top gloss line
    everyglb=\footnotesize \ttfamily,
    everyglc=\footnotesize \ttfamily,
    everyglpreamble=\itshape,
    aboveglbskip=-1ex,
    aboveglcskip=-1ex,
    aboveglftskip=-2ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the aligned lines and the free translation line
    interpartskip=1ex,% vertical space between parts of examples
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between aligned words
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between end of line and the right margin
    aboveexskip=1ex plus .4ex minus .4ex,% vertical space above examples
    belowexskip=1.5ex plus .4ex minus .4ex% vertical space below examples
}

\usepackage{caption}

\lingset{% my custom formatting for expex glosses
    belowglpreambleskip=-0.1ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the preamble and the top gloss line
%   everygla=\footnotesize,% removes the default italic formatting of the top gloss line
%   everyglb=\footnotesize \ttfamily,
%   everyglc=\footnotesize \ttfamily,
%    everyglpreamble=\itshape,
    aboveglftskip=-0.2ex,% shrinks the vertical space between the aligned lines and the free translation line
    interpartskip=1ex,% vertical space between parts of examples
    glspace=!0pt plus .2em,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between aligned words
    glrightskip=0pt plus .5\hsize,% improves line breaking by increasing the maximum horizontal space between end of line and the right margin
    aboveexskip=1ex plus .4ex minus .4ex,% vertical space above examples
    belowexskip=1.5ex plus .4ex minus .4ex% vertical space below examples
}



\usepackage{linguex} % für glossierte Beispiele
\let\eachwordone=\itshape

\usepackage{color} % evtl noetig, wenn die Links farbig sein sollen
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, linkcolor=black,}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear, %sets the Bibliography style to authoryear; chicago-authordate
citestyle=authoryear-comp %sets the Citation style to authoryear-icomp; chicago-authordate
]
{biblatex} 

\usepackage{url}

%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\space\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{centralbibliography.bib}
%.bibfile muss sich im selben Ordner befinden
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} % for quotes: commands: \enquote{}; \foreignquote{}; \hyphenquote{}; \textquote[{\cite{}}][<punct>]{text}tpunct; \blockquote[<cite>][]{text}; \hyphenblockquote[][]{}

\newenvironment*{singlespcquote} %sets the line spacing for blockquotes to single
    {\quote\singlespacing}
    {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlespcquote}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}%fuer schoene Tabellenlinien
\usepackage{tabulary} % für Tabellen (macht alle Spalten gleich lang)
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln} %für gestrichelte horizontale Linie in Tabellen mit \hdashline

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\Gloss}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\reference}[1]{(#1)}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % für Header und Footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % am Beginn einer Seite, die keine Header und Footer haben soll: \pagestyle{empty} = gar nichts, \pagestyle{plain} = nur Seitenzahl

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{Thesis Title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[C]{Author Name}

\usepackage{graphicx} % für Graphiken
%\graphicspath{ {graphics/} } % spezifiziert den Ordner, wo die Graphiken sind

%\usepackage{adjustbox} Hat nicht funktioniert - Möglichkeit, Tabellen auf Textbreite zu reduzieren?

\newenvironment{packed_item}{
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.5pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{itemize}}

\newenvironment{packed_enum}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\ex}{\vspace{\Exredux}\begin{singlespace}}{}{}
\renewcommand{\ExEnd}{%
    \ifnum\theExDepth=0\global\unembeddedfalse\end{singlespace}\vspace{.5\Exredux}\else%
    \end{list}\addtocounter{ExDepth}{-1}\ExEnd\fi}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{textcomp,xspace}
%\newcommand\la{\textlangle\xspace}  % set up short-form macros
%\newcommand\ra{\textrangle\xspace}  % definiert Kurzbefehle für eckige KLammern, je rechts und links
%\newcommand{\Ang}[1]{\la{#1}\ra}    % definiert einen Kurzbefehl um ein Wort in eckige Klammern zu setzen
\newcommand{\Ang}[1]{\textlangle\xspace{#1}\textrangle\xspace}

\begin{document}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you are loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which is just for pdftex and should never be used with xetex, then `\usepackage{fontspec-xetex}` which can only be used with xetex, but should be `\usepackage{fontspec}` the `-xetex` version is intended for internal code

Comment: textcomp and tipa are 8bit font packages that don't make  a lot of sense with Unicode tex but despite posting 150 lines of code you have not provided any example that produces any output or the error that you are asking about with xetex you can probably use angle brackets directly  ‹U+2039/U+203A›  ⟨U+27E8/U+27E9⟩